# laravel app not login in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am learning laravel step by step. I have successfully implemented basic model-view-controller. But i have problem when i tried using its authentication system. 
I have made table for storing user data as [image]

Pre included register form work perfect. After registration it even show i am logged in. But when i try to login with same credential which i entered in reg form. It wont allow me log in. 
I think the problem is in middleware cause when i enter wrong username/password it shows error that invalid credentials. But not for valid ones, its just redirect to login page without any errors. 
I am using laravel 5.0 and all files are as it is provided by laravel

Comment: Did you create the table with a migration? Normally Laravel expects the id to be lower-case `id`.

Comment: @samlev thanks man it works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel expects model ids to be lower case (`id` instead of `ID`). If you need to use a different field as an id, you can define it in your model like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'userid';
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```